# Why this Popen command returns an error in Python 2.7.12?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

Upon execution of this line:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("echo whatever", bufsize=-1, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
```

I get the following error in Python 2.7.12:

```
*** SyntaxError: SyntaxError('invalid syntax', ('<string>', 1, 1, '= subprocess.Popen("echo whatever", bufsize=-1, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, shell=True)'))
```

I'm using the `shell=True` in order to execute much more complicated commands (as a string parameter), but I've noticed that this throws an exception regardless of the command content. Any ideas why this can happen and how to fix it? I don't want to execute command with args in list, just pass a correct string.

Comment: you code runs in my machine, can you supply more info and your code that cause this error.

Comment: Works for me on Windows, as well.

Comment: there is nothing more to add, seriously. I'm also confused because this completely weird for me. Maybe issue is that I run it in the ipdb session? But how would that matter?